# python re.split adding an empty string for end of line(CRLF) while reading input from file

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python re module, trying to read from a file and count the words. But regardless of whatever pattern I give, its adding an empty string to the list of words, when it reaches end of line.

I am reading the inputfile which has EOL - CRLF

```
words  = re.split(r'[~\r\n]+|\.\s*|;\s*|,\s*|\s*|\.|\r\n|$', line)
```

Following is the input line and corresponding output.

```
This is a test line; to verify, the regex pattern used.

 ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'line', 'to', 'verify', 'the', 'regex', 'pattern', '
used', '']
```

Comment: Try to omit `|$` in the regex

Comment: If the input ends with a newline there is not much you can do with a single split regex because this final newline is either used to split the expression (producing empty string as last element) or becomes (in a modified regex) part of the last item.

Comment: That empty string has nothing to do with `CRLF`, the `.` is split on, and that's where the empty string is coming from.

Comment: Can't you just `pop()` it off or ``-1``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
line = "This is a test line; to verify, the regex pattern used."
regx = re.compile("(\w[\w']*\w|\w)")
regx.findall(line)

#output 
['This',
 'is',
 'a',
 'test',
 'line',
 'to',
 'verify',
 'the',
 'regex',
 'pattern',
 'used']
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
re.split(r'\W(?!\Z)', line)
```

Output:

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'line', '', 'to', 'verify', '', 'the', 'regex', 'pattern', 'used.']
```

Its not perfect (period with the word 'used'), but it'll do the job for counting words.

EDIT

To be honest, you should just be using a space as the delimiter, and nothing else. My answer and @CSMaverick answer don't work on for example
`hello-world I am`. To work for all the different cases, the regex would become quite dirty. I recommend you use something as simple as `re.split(r'\s', line)`.

Comment: just use `re.split('(?i)[^a-z]+(?!$)',line)` or simply `re.split('[^a-z]+(?!$)',line,flags=re.I)`  which can also be written as `re.split('[^a-zA-Z]+(?!$)',line)`this will take into consideration all your cases